# How can i resize a photo in a photogallery to reduce the loading time?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i created a photo gallery in jquery, it works fine,but if i add large photos (5mb, 4300x3000, 8mb, or something like this) there will be a lot of loading time. i am a photographer and all my photos have more than 5-6 mb. this is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/EChhQ/4/ ... i tried to make it work on fiddle, but i could not, but you got the idea, is the fancybox photogallery jquery:
html

```
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="img/activitate1/2008.jpg"><img  id="imgredus" src="img/activitate1/2008.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="img/activitate1/2009.jpg"><img id="imgredus" src="img/activitate1/2009.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="img/activitate1/2010.jpg"><img id="imgredus" src="img/activitate1/2010.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

css

```
#imgredus{
max-height:130px;
max-width:130px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:10px;
}

/*! fancyBox v2.1.4 fancyapps.com | fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license */
.fancybox-wrap,
.fancybox-skin,
.fancybox-outer,
.fancybox-inner,
.fancybox-image,
.fancybox-wrap iframe,
.fancybox-wrap object,
.fancybox-nav,
.fancybox-nav span,
.fancybox-tmp
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.fancybox-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8020;
}

.fancybox-skin {
    position: relative;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
}

.fancybox-opened {
    z-index: 8030;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.fancybox-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.fancybox-error {
    color: #444;
    font: 14px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-image, .fancybox-iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fancybox-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
}

#fancybox-loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    background-position: 0 -108px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8060;
}

#fancybox-loading div {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url('fancybox_loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

.fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -18px;
    right: -18px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url('blank.gif'); /* helps IE */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-prev {
    left: 0;
}

.fancybox-next {
    right: 0;
}

.fancybox-nav span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 34px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.fancybox-prev span {
    left: 10px;
    background-position: 0 -36px;
}

.fancybox-next span {
    right: 10px;
    background-position: 0 -72px;
}

.fancybox-nav:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-tmp {
    position: absolute;
    top: -99999px;
    left: -99999px;
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 99999px;
    max-height: 99999px;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

/* Overlay helper */

.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8010;
    background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Title helper */

.fancybox-title {
    visibility: hidden;
    font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 8050;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -35px;
    z-index: 8050;
    text-align: center;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap .child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -100%;
    padding: 2px 20px;
    background: transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
       -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #222;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-title-outside-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.fancybox-title-over-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

but you will find everything in the jsfiddle. So what should i change to prevent the loading time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resizing the images with CSS will make no difference as the file will remain the same size and still take the same amount of time to download onto the user's browser.

The only thing you can do is resize the actual image file which is being requested.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser haves to download the entire image before resizing, css reducing makes no difference, so you shoud generate thumbs manually or use a script in photoshop or whatever.